# Consolidating two tables with repeating results

Tags: sql, sqlite, t-sql

I am having a problem how to query two tables as shown

Table 1

```
id  module
1   Part1
2   Part2
3   Part3
4   Part4
```

Table 2

```
id  Town 
1    Town 1
2    Town 2
3    Town 4
```

Resulting query

```
Module Town
Part1  Town 1
Part2  Town 1
Part3  Town 1
Part4  Town 1
Part1  Town 2
Part2  Town 2
Part3  Town 2
Part4  Town 2
Part1  Town 4
Part2  Town 4
Part3  Town 4
Part4  Town 4
```

I tried using union but got a different result. Hoping for your kind solution to this problem of mine...

Comment: This is called a `cartesian product`.  You can use a `cross join` for such a thing: `select module, town from table1 cross join table2`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want implement a cartesian product you must use `CROSS JOIN` statement

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.module, table2.town
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

You can see ***[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)*** about JOINs operation in SQLite